# How to decompress/deflate zlib data [rfc1951]?

Tags: red

I am looking for decompressing data according to the deflate compression mechanism [rfc1951].

The linux command for this mechanism is:
zlib-flate -uncompress

I try the Red command decompress with refinements deflate
, but it crashes or the result is wrong (it looks like a crash or a memory dump).

Is there a sample to use decompress/deflate ?

```
>> type? b1
== binary!
>> length? b1
== 326
>> decompress/deflate b1 326

*** Runtime Error 16: invalid virtual address
*** at: 080AB560h
```

Comment: I know it's not much help, but it works OK on macos 10.14.6 with Red 0.6.4 build 2-July-2021.  I was able to `compress/flate` a string, and then `decompress/deflate` the binary object. Maybe get the latest distribution from the site? Or see if an older release worked?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, Red's implementation of DEFLATE is buggy and likely won't be able to decompress data that it itself did not compress.

If you still experience this crash with the [latest Linux build](https://static.red-lang.org/dl/auto/linux/red-latest), please file a [ticket](https://github.com/red/red/issues) for it.

Comment: `Red 0.6.4 for Linux built 22-Nov-2018/2:40:38+02:00 commit #755eb94` does not generate an error to decompress ... but in my test case, it generates 4 extra bytes compared with the linux command `zlib-flate -uncompress`. PS `decompress/zlib` and `decompress/zlib/deflate` output the same result.